# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at Module._compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, truffle

Here's my code for election.js:

```
import { isMainThread } from "worker_threads";
import { AssertionError } from "assert";

var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");

contract("Election",function(accounts){
    it("initializes with two candidates",function(){
        return Election.deployed().then(function(instance){
            return instance.candidatesCount();
        }).then(function(count){ 
            AssertionError.equal(count,2);
        });
    });
});
```

When I am trying to test it using:

```
truffle test
```

The following error is displaying at the terminal:

```
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

/home/shreyas/election/test/election.js:1 import { isMainThread } from "worker_threads";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/test.js:138:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/test.js:137:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5) Truffle v5.1.8 (core: 5.1.8) Node v12.3.1
```

Please help me in dealing with this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever is loading `election.js` isn't loading it as an ESM module, so it doesn't know what `import {` means. Either tell it that it's dealing with ESM modules (if it can deal with them), or use Node.js's old-style CJS modules instead.

Comment: The `import` keyword is invalid syntax in js files. Node is interpreting your file as a js file (hint the mention of cjs which is a reference to common js which is the original module system for node.js) so using the `import` keyword is a syntax error. The `import` keyword is only supported in module files (mjs files)

Comment: Actually I am a beginner dealing with this .

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Will you please tell me what modifications I should do?

Comment: or you? @slebetman

Comment: For `worker_threads` at least it is not an es6 module so it cannot be used with `import` anyway. So just use `require` with it. I'm not sure about `assert` but just try using `require` with that anyway. So far nothing in Truffle supports es6 modules so you are not supposed to use `import` in general with Truffle. Truffle libraries tend to expect `require` (they tend to be cjs modules)

Comment: @slebetman - All of the built-in Node.js modules can be `import`ed, including `"worker_threads"`. But only in an ESM module, of course.

Comment: @ShreyasJain - You'll have to refer to the documentation and examples of the tool you're using (`truffle`, I guess). I don't happen to be familiar with it.